# Difficulty understanding how recursion works in C

Tags: c, recursion

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* --- Prototype of functions --- */
void upton(int n); /* recursive function to print the numbers from 1 to n */

/* ========================================================================= */
main()
{
  upton(20); /* prints numbers from 1 to 20 on the screen */
  
  system("PAUSE");
  return 0;                                     
}

void upton(int n)
{
  if(n<1) return;    /* returns if n less than 1 */
  
  upton(n-1);        /* recursive call with n-1 */
  printf("%d\n",n);  /* will print after successive recursions */
}
```

The above code generates the following output:

```
1
2
3
4
...
```

Would anyone know how to explain to me how printf() is managing to be executed at each pass of the recursion of the upton() function?

I always understood that the program would be stuck inside the recursion until the recursion was invalidated. And, as printf() is after the recursion, I don't understand how it is getting executed... And, as the recursion is 'upton(n-1)', how is the result being printed in ascending order?

---- Edited ----

@pm100 @Allan Vento @olliejones

Let me see if I understood correctly:

So, when I use a recursion, each time it is executed it stores the following information in a stack level:

#1 → Current value of the recursive variable (n).

#2 → Address of the position where the function was "paused" [in this case, at each pass of the recursion the function is "paused" in line 'upton(n-1)'].

When the recursion is finally invalidated (n<1), the function that called it [void upton(int n)] starts executing everything that was saved on the stack (the last level saved on the stack will be the first to be be executed) and, with that, everything that was "paused" below the recursion line will also be executed at each level of the stack.

Is my conclusion correct?

I made the following modification to test this hypothesis:

```
main()
{
  upton(6); /* prints numbers from 1 to 6 on the screen */

  system("PAUSE");
  return 0;
}

void upton(int n)
{
  static int test=1;
  static char letter='f';

  if(n<1) return;    /* returns if n less than 1 */

  upton(n-1);        /* recursive call with n-1 */

  /* Tests after recursion */
  printf("\nn=%d\n", n);
  printf("Hello!\n");
  printf("Test= %d%c\n",test, letter);
  test++;
  letter--;
}
```

And the output obtained was this:

```
n=1
Hello!
Test= 1f

n=2
Hello!
Test= 2e

n=3
Hello!
Test= 3d

n=4
Hello!
Test= 4c

n=5
Hello!
Test= 5b

n=6
Hello!
Test= 6a
```

Comment: Notice that the recursed variable `n` starts at 20 and counts down. Also notice that some compilers can turn tail recursion into iteration, but this sample code cannot tail-recurse because there's something after the recursion call, the totally confusing printf. Iteration is better than recursion, because you can't get, well, a Stack Overflow. So it's an example of what NOT to do.

Comment: Each caller pushes the arguments on the stack. Within `upton()` it's `n - 1` and in `main()` it's `6`. Nothing is invalidated.  It's called the "base case" and what stops the recursion going on "forever". It doesn't execute what is stored on the stack, code is stored in the text segment, however the return address (as you noted) functions returns to that address by implicitly changing the function pointer (FP) register.
A

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You call the recursive function before the `printf()` till you get to base case `n = 0`,  Then you return to your previous stack frame and  `printf(..., 1)` executes.  Then you return to stack frame before that and execute `printf(..., 2)` etc.

I suggest you modify your recursive function to print something before and after:

```
void upton(int n) {
  if(n<1) return;
  printf("before: %d\n", n);
  upton(n-1);
  printf("after: %d\n", n);
}
```

and you will get this output:

```
before: 20
before: 19
before: 18
before: 17
before: 16
before: 15
before: 14
before: 13
before: 12
before: 11
before: 10
before: 9
before: 8
before: 7
before: 6
before: 5
before: 4
before: 3
before: 2
before: 1
after: 1
after: 2
after: 3
after: 4
after: 5
after: 6
after: 7
after: 8
after: 9
after: 10
after: 11
after: 12
after: 13
after: 14
after: 15
after: 16
after: 17
after: 18
after: 19
after: 20
```

Recursive algorithms usually yield compact code but the C Standard does not specify tail call optimization.  If your compiler doesn't have that optimization your stack is bound by the values of your input arguments, and if your input is sufficiently large your program will crash when it runs out of stack space.

Answer (score 5):

upton keeeps calling itself until n is < 1. Lets start with 5 rather than 20

```
 upton(5) calls
  upton(4) calls
     upton(3) calls
      upton(2) calls
        upton(1) calls
          upton(0) returns
        upton(1) prints  1
      upton(2) prints 2
    upton(3) prints 3
  upton(4) prints 4
 upton(5) prints 5
```